# Ionic Avoid Talkback reads appname and webview

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, accessibility

We have an Ionic APP with Angular, but for accessibility when we use Android TalkBack it start reading the AppName and WebView, but we don't want to read that part, we only want to read the content of the visible top Div ¿is that possible?

Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: There’s some context missing. Is TalkBack reading the AppName initially and when the window gets focused, or on other occasions, too?

Comment: when the window gets focused, I mean the app is open, then we start TalkBack and then the first element to read is: AppName ... WebView ...

Comment: And why would you want to change that?

Comment: Because we don't need to listen to the name of the window or WebView, we just want to listen to the main content

Comment: Are you using the screen reader for other applications, too? It’s quite critical for a screen reader to identify the window within the desktop system, it’s what screen reader users need, and you cannot change it.